# How to make this Binary serach tree insert method work

Tags: java, insert, boolean, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am implementing different methods in a binary search tree and  am  stuck on the insert method as it just doesn't seem to work.

I have been trying to implement the insert method for a while now but nothing seems to work it's always returning null. This method takes a user and adds it to the database. Using the User class.

```
    public boolean beFriend(User friend) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    User node = friend;
    if (friend == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    }
    if(root == friend) {
        return false;
    } else if(root.getKey() < friend.getKey()) {
        if(root.getLeft() != null) {
            root.setLeft(friend);
            return true;
        } else {
            root.setLeft(node);
            return true;
        }
    } else { if(root.getRight() != null) {
            root.setRight(friend);
        } else {
            root.setRight(node);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

I expect the User friend to be added to the database and output its details but the output that I am currently getting is null.

Comment: Is variable `root` known inside the function?

Comment: Hey @Theo Its set as a instance variable on top of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't define "root" in your method, therefore it's always null. You should define "root" to compare with friend and getting any data from it.

Comment: Hey @Bogachev_Ilia I tried what u recommended but still getting the same output.

Comment: What are you expected from "root"? Is it another data from database? If yes, you should add it to your method like this:"public boolean beFriend(User friend, User root)"

Comment: The root is set at top of the  Binary search tree class as an instance variable public User root. I am supposed to add the new User friend in the database according to its key.

Comment: review comment: adding a snippet showing the change would probably help the OP easily understand your answer.